# How can i change JDateChooser background and foreground color

Tags: java, jdatechooser, background-foreground

I need to change `JDateChooser` background and foreground color, i changed the color using  **LaF** property window,but nothing happens

[image]

Then i also used following code to solve this,

```
BorrowDateChooser.setBackground(new Color(51,51,51));
```

but it also not working for me,what can i do for this problem

Comment: Isn't it related to the issue described in this link ? https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/jdatechooser-setenabled-color.749473/

Answer (score 0):

Use code below to change the jdatechooser background:

```
       for( Component c : jDateChooser1.getComponents()){
((JComponent)c).setBackground(Color.RED);
```

}

```
  for( Component c : jDateChooser2.getComponents()){
((JComponent)c).setBackground(Color.RED);
```

}

the result of example picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfh8G.png)